# css3 animation is not working in android and ios browsers

Tags: android, ios, css

**html code:**

```css
.iconItem{display:inline-block;width:136px; height:136px;text-align:center; margin:15px 15px;position:relative; z-index:0;color:#FFF; text-decoration:none; outline:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);}
.itemBg{ width:100%; height:100%; background:rgba(9,52,89,0.3);position:absolute; z-index:5; top:0; left:0; border-radius:100%;transition:All 0.4s ease-in-out;}
.itemText{width:100%;position:absolute; z-index:15; top:87px; left:0; text-align:center;}

.iconItem:hover .itemBg,.itemRotate{background:url(http://trtesth5.wlb.pw/wlb_m/images/bg_rotate.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 -webkit-animation:myrotate 2s linear infinite running;
 -moz-animation:myrotate 2s linear infinite running;
 animation:myrotate 2s linear infinite running;
}
@-webkit-keyframes myrotate{
 0%   {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
 100% {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes myrotate{
 0%   {-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);}
 100% {-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes myrotate{
 0%   {transform:rotate(0deg);}
 100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<a class="iconItem" href="#"><div class="itemBg"></div><div class="iconG icon01"></div><span class="itemText">WIFI</span></a>
```

or you can see the demo on this site:http://trtesth5.wlb.pw/wlb_m/

I want the class 'itemBg' rotate 360 degree when touch on the tab 'a',it is working in Firefox and Chrome on PC ,but it is not working on Androd and IOS devices. I don't know why.Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: The fact that you are using prefixed keyframes doesn't mean that the properties you are animating should have the same prefix or that the unprefixed keyframes doesn't need to have the prefixed transformations.